# 14.04 ubuntu complete install resolution problem

Tags: 14.04, resolution

first time linux user,
using an old fijitsu siemens v5535, intel pentium dual core, 2gb ram

I cant get out of 640x480 resolution ive tried xrandr functions, it says my max size is 640x480 which is driving me up the wall as i cant see half the window for all the programs and settings especially display settings, i cant detect displays, stuck in "built in display" any tips would be appreciated

Comment: xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        73.0* 
this is what i get

Comment: what's the make and model of your monitor/display?

Comment: its all built in to the laptop fujitsu siemens esprimo mobile v5535

Comment: screen is capable of 1280x800 it says here http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/COMP/fpcap/notebooks/previous/factsheet_v5535.pdf but the SIS graphics card uses shared memory. How much RAM is installed in it?

Comment: its 2 gb of ram, and i set the shared memory to 256 max it will go

Comment: so i just put it in recovery mode, then put it in failsafe graphic mode, after it would allow me up put the resolution into 1024x768 which worked fine but then i rebooted back to normal and it just went back to 640x480 and then wouldnt let me change it in regular boot

Answer (score 0):

Use `ALT+LEFT MOUSE BUTTON`, on windows, to grab them and move them around, you will be able to see more content to do more diagnostic things and operations

And try this: http://blog.bigsmoke.us/2011/01/18/ubuntu-sis-671-driver

P.S For gain a `root` permissions type:

`sudo passwd` and type new **root** password twice (**root** it's like a Admin account in Windows, **superuser** so you must **remember** this password)

Then just type in console `su` before all operations, your **root** password and perform **all** operations now with **full** permission

Comment: i can get the resolution to change in recovery mode,failsafe graphic mode, then once i reboot it comes up with errors saying saved graphic configuration doesnt work basically

Comment: the files is says to copy and paste it wont allow me permission to past them into drivers

Comment: type in console `su` before all operations